# Rounding in an array equation?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm hoping someone can help me out...
Is there a way to round:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( (If(ISBLANK(A2:A),"", (H2:H*10^-3)/((E2:E*10^-3)*(F2:F*10^-3)*(G2:G*10^-3)))))
```

to two decimal places in the equation itself?

Answer (score 1):

- try like this:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A), ,
   ROUND((H2:H*10^-3)/((E2:E*10^-3)*(F2:F*10^-3)*(G2:G*10^-3)), 2)))
  ```

Comment: @EugeneLightning https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers